# RTT calculation using tcptrace

Tags: tcp, tcpdump, tcptrace

For the below attached tcptrace output (this is taken from the site http://tcptrace.org/manual/index.html under RTT stats)

```
1 arg remaining, starting with 'indica.dmp.gz'
Ostermann's tcptrace -- version 6.4.5 -- Fri Jun 13, 2003

153 packets seen, 153 TCP packets traced
elapsed wallclock time: 0:00:00.128422, 1191 pkts/sec analyzed
trace file elapsed time: 0:00:19.092645
TCP connection info:
1 TCP connection traced:
TCP connection 1:
    host a:        192.168.0.70:32791
    host b:        webco.ent.ohiou.edu:23
    complete conn: yes
    first packet:  Thu Aug 29 18:54:54.782937 2002
    last packet:   Thu Aug 29 18:55:13.875583 2002
    elapsed time:  0:00:19.092645
    total packets: 153
    filename:      indica.dmp.gz
   a->b:                  b->a:
     total packets:            91           total packets:            62      
           . . .                                  . . .
           . . .                                  . . .
     throughput:               10 Bps       throughput:               94 Bps  

     RTT samples:              48           RTT samples:              47      
     RTT min:                74.1 ms        RTT min:                 0.1 ms   
     RTT max:               204.0 ms        RTT max:                38.8 ms   
     RTT avg:               108.6 ms        RTT avg:                 8.1 ms   
     RTT stdev:              44.2 ms        RTT stdev:              14.7 ms   

     RTT from 3WHS:          75.0 ms        RTT from 3WHS:           0.1 ms   

     RTT full_sz smpls:         1           RTT full_sz smpls:         1      
     RTT full_sz min:        79.5 ms        RTT full_sz min:         0.1 ms   
     RTT full_sz max:        79.5 ms        RTT full_sz max:         0.1 ms   
     RTT full_sz avg:        79.5 ms        RTT full_sz avg:         0.1 ms   
     RTT full_sz stdev:       0.0 ms        RTT full_sz stdev:       0.0 ms   

     post-loss acks:            0           post-loss acks:            0
```

So the question I have is that if you see RTT average for a->b and for b->a there is a major difference in the values. I dont expect them to be exaclty the same but the difference is quite big. I think there is something happening behind the scene in the way RTT is being calculated which I am not sure of.

Comment: I know its not tcpdump related but it wont let me create a new tag for tcptrace.

Answer (score 5):

**Summary:** *Make sure you look at the RTT for the correct half of the conversation, depending on where you made the capture*

[This answer](http://www.tcptrace.org/archive/0289.html) explains that tcptrace uses the difference between timestamps of the data segment and that of the ACK that acknowledges it to calculate RTT. This means that ***the RTT calculation will depend on where you are capturing the trace***

For example, if you are capturing packets on node A, you will see A's ACK almost immediately after you see the corresponding segment arriving from node B and thus see a very low value for RTT in the B->A segments. For A->B segments you will be measuring the real RTT as a 'real' round-trip will have occurred between seeing the segment from A and the corresponding ACK from b.

If you made the capture on node b the situation would be reversed, and if you made the capture somewhere in the middle the 'true' RTT would be approximately the sum of A->B + B->A.

Answer (score 0):

The RTT calculations are not made at the sender node. They could have been made at a point along the path. The a->b and b->a is not necessarily between the sender and receiver nodes.

It can be something like this

`S--A--------->R` where S is Sender and R is receiver and A is some point between S and R. a->b can represent the RTT from A to R while b->a can represent RTT from A to S.